# add next & back buttons for custom gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code :

```
$(function(){
    $('.words-gallery div:gt(0)').hide();
    
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.words-gallery > div:first')    
        .fadeOut(1000)    
        .next()
        .delay(995)
        .fadeIn(1000)    
        .end()    
        .appendTo('.words-gallery');},  
    3000);
    
});
```

This code will make a gallery from `DIVs` and every `3000` will hide the current `DIV` and show the next one.

I was trying to add next & back buttons but it's not working with me.

here is my fiddle:

#### http://www.jsfiddle.net/jUrNx

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: simply put two button near image and implement jQuery `.next()` and `.prev()`  on both buttons.

Comment: I did it as you said but when I use the prev button it will not work until I pres the next button first, Why??

Comment: paste your code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: done, http://jsfiddle.net/jUrNx/

Comment: i'll definately solve you problem but currently i m at office, solve u later. meanwhil i paste your fiddle in the question. somebody must helps u. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)?  It will let you do everything you're asking and more.  There is even a specific [example using "next/prev"](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html).

**Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Qz5T/**

Essentially, you would set up your code as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav"><a id="prev2" href="#">Prev</a> <a id="next2" href="#">Next</a></div>
<div class="words-gallery">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>333</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.words-gallery').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 3000, 
    next:   '#next2', 
    prev:   '#prev2' 
});
```